# Ratio of areas determined by a square inscribed in the corner of a right triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, triangles, ratio

I’m having trouble working out how to algebraically get to the answer of this question. (See original image below.)

> A square is drawn in the corner of a right-angled triangle with side lengths $a$, $b$, and [hypotenuse] $c$, as shown.
>
> Which expression gives the ratio of the unshaded area [inside the triangle, but outside the square] to the shaded area [of the square] in all cases?
>
> - (A) $1:1$
> - (B) $c:(a+b)$
> - (C) $a b: c^2$
> - (D) $( a + b )^2 : 2 c^2$
> - (E) $c^2 : 2 a b$
>
> Apparently the answer is $c^2 : 2 a b$ (choice E), but how?

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

---

[image]

(Please ignore the pen marks! They are incorrect assumptions a friend made on the diagram.)

Comment: Do you see any similar triangles in the figure, and can you see how to use them to determine the length of the side of the square?

Comment: Hi, yeah all three triangles in the diagram are similar, but I don't know how to use them to determine the length of the side of the square. I ended up splitting a and b and calling them a1/a2 and b1/b2, but that made it confusing.

Comment: Suppose the side of the square is $s$. What are the sides of the two smaller triangles?

Comment: (a-s) and (b-s)? Or am I missing something easier?

Comment: Good! Specifically, $a-s$ and $b-s$ are *two* of the legs. (I meant "legs", not "sides".) The two other legs are ... *what?* And what proportion links all four of these values?

Comment: So the other two legs would be "s" as they share the same side as the square. Could you set up a ratio and say that (a-s)/s = (b-s)/s?

Comment: *So close!* ... Make sure the proportion matches the corresponding legs in the correct order.

Comment: Ah I see, so would it be (a-s)/(b-s)= (s/s) which is effectively 1?

Comment: Well, $s/s$ *is* $1$, but that's irrelevant. :) Going back to your original proportion, the fractions should look like "(horizontal leg) / (vertical leg)". So, $(a-s)/s$ is fine on the left; but on the right ...

Comment: Ohhh I get it, that would make it (a-s)/s= s/(b-s)?

Comment: *Boom!* Right! Can you solve that for $s$ and get all the pieces from here?

Comment: I think that's all I needed to finish the question, thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the side of the square is $x$. Then, using similarity of triangles, $\frac{b-x}{x}=\frac{x}{a-x}$ or $(b-x)(a-x)=x^2$; $ab-ax-bx+x^2=x^2$; $ab=x(a+b)$ or $x=\frac{ab}{a+b}$. Thus, the shaded area is $\frac{(ab)^2}{(a+b)^2}$. 
The unshaded area is $$0.5x(b-x)+0.5x(a-x)=0.5\left(\frac{ab}{a+b}(b-\frac{ab}{a+b})+\frac{ab}{a+b}(a-\frac{ab}{a+b}\right)=\frac{ab(b^2+a^2)}{2(a+b)^2}=\frac{abc^2}{2(a+b)^2}$$ so the final ratio is $$\frac{2ab}{c^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for this, was just wondering how you went from working out both areas to then finding the final ratio? I haven't done ratios in a while sorry!

Comment: Wait, nevermind I worked it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the side length of the square.

By similarity,

- The hypotenuse of the lower small right triangle is $\bigl({\large{\frac{c}{b}}}\bigr)x$.$\\[4pt]$

  The hypotenuse of the upper small right triangle is $\bigl({\large{\frac{c}{a}}}\bigr)x$.

Hence we get
$$\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)x+\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)x=c$$
which yields
$$x=\frac{ab}{a+b}$$
If $S,U$ are the respective areas of the shaded and unshaded regions, then

- $S=x^2$$\\[4pt]$

  $U=\bigl({\large{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigr)ab-x^2$

hence, the required ratio can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
\frac{U}{S}
&=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)ab-x^2}{x^2}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)ab}{x^2}-1\\[4pt]
&=\left(
\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)ab
\right)
\left({\small{\frac{1}{x}}}\right)^2
-1
\\[4pt]
&=\left(
\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)ab
\right)
\left({\small{\frac{a+b}{ab}}}\right)^2
-1
\\[4pt]
&=\frac{(a+b)^2}{2ab}-1\\[4pt]
&=\frac{(a+b)^2-2ab}{2ab}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{c^2}{2ab}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}